# Replicating the "Calculate Geometry" table tool in python

Tags: arcpy

I'm trying to automate a very tedious process in our company that involves switching the data frame's coordinate system and performing calculate geometry on a couple of fields, these are the two situations I'm having trouble with :

First situation would be !SHAPE.CENTROID.X.! using data source's coordinate system with the unit conversion specified in the picture

[image]

Second is switching the data frame coordinate system, choosing to use it and perform the following calculation :

[image]

So, two main questions :

1) How to switch the data frame's coordinate system and calculate based on it

2) Get !SHAPE.CENTROID.X.! with the specified unit on picture 1

I'm using `arcpy.CalculateField_management` for this since there already is a selection

I really searched for this one but couldn't find what I'm looking for

Comment: It's not quite clear what your broader context is. Do you have a list of feature classes that you need to calculate centroids for using two separate coordinate systems? Do you have a map within which you need to iterate over layers and calculate centroids using two separate coordinate systems? Do you have a series of maps within which you need to grab a single layer and calculate centroids...? The iteration is the challenge, but we don't know what you're iterating over.

Comment: See: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm

Comment: @Tom feature class containing points

Comment: Since you have Points, I don't think you need Shape.Centroid.X just Shape.X. They might produce identical results.

Comment: @Mojimi, so does it need to be repeated on the same feature class? Where is the "tedious" part coming in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the spatial reference of the data frame object in Python.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
df.spatialReference = 31982 # SIRGAS_2000_UTM_Zone_22S
```

However, I think it will be much more efficient to leave the data frame as is and just project the point geometry on the fly.

```
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(31982) # SIRGAS_2000_UTM_Zone_22S
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(<layer_name>, ["SHAPE@", "X", "Y", "newX", "newY"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        newGeom = row[0].projectAs(sr)
        row[1] = row[0].centroid.X # current X
        row[2] = row[0].centroid.Y # current Y
        row[3] = newGeom.centroid.X # projected X
        row[4] = newGeom.centroid.Y # projected Y
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Add Geometry Attributes tool will allow you to perform many of the functions found in the Calculate Geometry tool from within a model or Python script.

Comment: Doesn't that add fields? They already exist, just need to update them

Comment: Excellent, you can also define the Coordinate System inside the Add Geometry Attributes tool.